# Deepin: Switch to next desktop

Tags: configuration, desktop, settings, deepin

Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch to either or:

- Switch to desktop on the right. i.e. [ctrl + ->]
- Switch to desktop on the left. i.e. [ctrl + <-]
- Switch to 3rd desktop. i.e. [ctrl + 3]

I've been trying to find it but the topic is so polluted with so many other searches related that I have not been able to find anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! They are:

- Win/Super + Right Arrow Key
- Win/Super + Left Arrow Key
- Win/Super + 3

If you press F1 while beeing on the Desktop it shows a little manual where you can find more details.

In the keyboard section in the setting you will find a list and an option to configure new shortcuts.